# Kotest with Fiddler

Tags: fiddler, kotest

I am trying to rewrite our automatic tests to Kotest.
Previously we were using plain AndroidInstrumentation tests running on a device. The tests rewritten to Kotest do work well, however I am not able to force them to use Fiddler running on the same machine the tests are running. Some tests are pretty complex, so just logging request/response is definitelly not enough. I need to have the power of Fiddler to be able to debug occasional problems. The Fiddler shows all kind of connections running from my computer (Firefox, Slack, gradle, etc.) but connections performed by the kotest are not catched at all - not just unredable - they are not there at all.

I was googling a lot, most of the times it is suggested to set the proxy via gradle.properties, but that does not do anything. Only the tests fail if the proxy is set wrong, but with correct one the communication is still not visible in Fiddler proxy.